# Send SMS to user when password is reset in AD

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, sms

I'd like to send user a SMS when their password has been reset in Active Directory. The purpose is to notify them to use different password to login.

How can I do this?

Is there an event that is fired when reset is performed that I could use to run a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A security event id 4724 success audit is recorded when an administrative password reset is performed.  It is possible to trigger a task action on the domain controller where this occurs, but it would be more optimal to have an event log central collector and trigger the task there.

https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4724

Answer (score 0):

With a Powershell script, You can send an email when a user change their password (based on Event ID and user) but you can't send a SMS to the user from the Active Directory. You will need a third party software to do this (if any). In my case, I use a powershell script to send an email every time the user lockout his account. The script should be running on your domain controllers.